# Evenly spread views inside a cardview Horizontaly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I need help, I have ConstraintLayout and a few child views, I also have a card view which is a child view of the ConstraintLayout, I need to spread it evenly 3 views on the card view using only one ConstraintLayout to keep the flat hierarchy

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_normal">

    <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="84dp"
        android:layout_height="84dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/full_name"
        style="@style/Material.Headline6.Light"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/none"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/profile_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Roger Mphile Nkosi" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/job_title"
        style="@style/Material.Subtitle1.Light"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/none"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/profile_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/full_name"
        tools:text="Android Developer" />
    
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/job_title"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/years_title"
        style="@style/Material.Caption.Light"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/coffees_title"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profile_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/job_title"
        tools:text="Years" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/coffees_title"
        style="@style/Material.Caption.Light"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/bugs_title"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/years_title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/job_title"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        tools:text="Coffees" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bugs_title"
        style="@style/Material.Caption.Light"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/coffees_title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/job_title"
        tools:text="Bugs" />
    
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have tried chain styles but no winning. Is it possible to achieve what I want to achieve using only one ConstraintLayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is with your xml structure of the 3 views which are direct children of the `CardView` instead of a `ConstraintLayout` so any constraints attributes you apply there cannot work because the direct parent is the `CardView`.

Therefore your structure should look like this:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/years_title"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/coffees_title" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/bugs_title"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Now to evenly spread the above 3 views in the `ConstraintLayout` horizontally you have to apply for each `TextView` the attribute `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"`, the  `android:layout_width="0dp"` and link every `TextView` child with its neighbours eg. for the second `TextView` will be: `app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/years_title"` , `app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/bugs_title"`.

So your new structure of the `CardView` should look like the below:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/job_title"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/profile_image"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/years_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/coffees_title"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
            tools:text="Years" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/coffees_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/years_title"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/bugs_title"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
            tools:text="Coffees" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bugs_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/coffees_title"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
            tools:text="Bugs" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**Result:**

[image: result1_image]

Or in case you want the `CardView` to wrap to its content it should look like this:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/job_title"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/profile_image">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/years_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/coffees_title"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
            tools:text="Years" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/coffees_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/years_title"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/bugs_title"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
            tools:text="Coffees" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bugs_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/coffees_title"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
            tools:text="Bugs" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**Result:**

[image: reasult2_image]

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer, I managed to get it to work last night, my solution is very much close to yours. I realized I cannot achieve a flat hierarchy completely and had to have a ConstraintLayout as a child of CardView.